# Looking for "full-size" on-screen keyboard layout for Honeycomb

Tags: keyboard, tablet

All on-screen keyboards available in the market seem to be designed for phones, and as such most of them follow the "37-key" layout. However, using this layout on large (10") android screen is painful and breaks all quick typing habits. Even keyboards that try to mimc desktop keyboard are limited to letters and move special characters to separate layout or to other row of keys.

So the question is whether there's a soft keyboard available which completely mimics the main part of the regular computer keyboard, with digits row and all extra keys right to letters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like [Hacker's Keyboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) might be a good try for you. It doesn't have some of the rightmost keys (insert, end, page up/down, also F1-F12) visibly displayed on the main layout, but they are available by pressing the "Fn" key. Here's the layout on a tablet:

[image]

Comment: Hadn't realized how much I missed the track ball from my phone until I saw those cursor keys! Maybe I have fat fingers, but moving one character back or forward is a chore.